# How to inflate class com.google.android.maps.MapView?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have instance (mv) of class `com.google.android.maps.MapView` in my MapActivity. and I am initializing it with `mv= (com.google.android.maps.MapView) findViewById(R.id.mvId);`

Now, In my xml layout file mapview is defined like this:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mvId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Which is causing classCastException as it should be.
Now, If i'm using mapview layout like this -

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/mvId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

This is showing Class Inflating Exception.

Please note It is compulsory to use instance of `com.google.android.maps.MapView` in MapActivity. What should I do? Is there any way to cast between two mapviews or how to inflate class `com.google.android.maps.MapView` in Layout file. What is difference between gms.maps.MapView and maps.MapView?

Comment: Post your MainActivity please

Comment: The class name is `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`. If you're going to use a wrong name in the XML layout you're going to get an exception while inflating. If you're going to perform cast to somethinng else you're going to get `ClassCastException`.

Comment: We Cannot cast from `com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView` to `com.google.android.maps.MapView`.

Comment: @Skizo, MainActivity has nothing but `MapView mv= (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mvId);` And after that, I need to call method `mv.getOverlays().add(overlay);` So I need instance of class `com.google.android.maps.MapView`. But How to inflate it in layout file? Also FYI I have used `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` in manifest and also i'm extending MainActivity to MapActivity.